# Scriptalicious - Appear on Dynamically Created Element

Tags: ajax, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I'm new to Prototype (I've used jQuery for years) and I'm trying to fade an element in that has been inserted into the DOM via an ajax request.

I've tried the following:

```
$('element').insert({
  bottom: '<div id="element2" style="display:none;">Test</div>'
});

new Effect.Appear( 'element2', { duration: 0.25 } );
```

The element is successfully inserted, but it remains hidden.

Comment: put the appear call in `done` chained to insert

Answer (score 0):

according to this fiddle it works http://jsfiddle.net/8KA6u/ - however you might have a race condition. Try running the Appear on the next run of the event loop by wrapping it in a `setTimeout()` with 0 delay

```
$('element').insert({
    bottom: '<div id="element2" style="display:none;">Test</div>'
});

setTimeout(function(){
    new Effect.Appear( 'element2', { duration: 0.25 } );
},0);
```

Scriptaculous also adds some of the Effect methods directly to the element so you can run them like this

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('element2').appear({duration:0.25});
},0);
```

List of methods added to the elements
http://madrobby.github.io/scriptaculous/effect-methods/